# Getting twig partial markup in controller throws error?

Tags: php, octobercms

I'm trying to get rendered twig content in a plugin controller. I'm using `CmsCompoundObject` to load a partial but it's throwing an error.

```php
$theme = Theme::getActiveThemeCode();
$markup = CmsCompoundObject::load($theme, "partials/test.htm")->getTwigContent();
```

> The from property is invalid, make sure that Cms\Classes\CmsCompoundObject has a string value for its $dirName property (use '' if not using directories)
>
> ../october/rain/src/Halcyon/Builder.php line 309

Looking at the code, this is where it's throwing the error:

```php
/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function runSelect()
{
    if (!is_string($this->from)) {
        throw new ApplicationException(sprintf("The from property is invalid, make sure that %s has a string value for its \$dirName property (use '' if not using directories)", get_class($this->model)));
    }

    if ($this->selectSingle) {
        list($name, $extension) = $this->selectSingle;
        return $this->datasource->selectOne($this->from, $name, $extension);
    }
}
```

`$theme` *is* a string and not empty, it properly gets the current theme so I'm not sure why it's saying invalid.

Answer (score 0):

OctoberCMS Slack channel helped me find the solution.

First was to use `Partial` instead of `CmsCompoundObject` and the 2nd was to remove "partials/" from the path name as the `Partial` class already knows to look in that directory.

```php
$theme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
$markup = Partial::load($theme, "test.htm")->getTwigContent();
```